# Embed a form inside a modal

Tags: forms, javascript, nodes

I have a modal in my form.

```
$form['myid_print_preview_modal'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',              
  '#markup' =>            
    '<div id="myid_print_preview_modal" title="ID Preview">                                                           
    </div>',                                    
);
```

I want to embed a set of form controls in my modal like textfield, buttons and etc. Is it possible? A simple example would be good for my comprehension. I don't want to use any existing module. I want to go hard code.

Comment: Yes. Definitely it is possible.

Comment: embed the fields inside the form or use webform module and open it with modal

Comment: @Drupalist --> An example would be good for my better comprehension.

Comment: @Qerjiuthn Here you could have an example. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/233178/load-form-via-ajax-and-submit-by-ajax-not-working/244801#244801 .Basically it's a link to a route, the link has 'use-ajax' class. Then linked controller return a form into a ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module. This module supports different kinds of fields that might be needed in your form. This module also supports Ajax submission.

After installing this module and building the form, use [Modal Forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms) module.

> Modal forms make use of the modal feature in the ctools module to open some common forms in a modal window.
>   Supported forms

- Log in (modal_forms/nojs/login)
- Request new password (modal_forms/nojs/password)
- Create new account (modal_forms/nojs/register)
- Contact (modal_forms/nojs/contact)
- Comment (modal_forms/nojs/comment/reply/%node)
- Webform (modal_forms/nojs/webform/%node)

So in this way no coding is needed.